# Using ROLLUP in query... Small question

Tags: sql, database, oracle

It is a "table_one" in oracle database:

```
COL1 COL2
-----------------
2 4
2 1
13 14
13 15
```

I have this query:

SELECT col1, sum(col2) FROM table_one GROUP BY ROLLUP(col1, col2);

After query execute I have:

```
------------
2    1
2    4
2    5
13   14
13   15
13   29
     34
```

but i need in another way, like this:

```
------------
2    1
2    4
2    5
13   14
13   15
13   29
```

without summary of all columns
How I can change my query..... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem. The first is to use grouping sets to define exactly what summary groups you want created.

In this case, you can define to group on (col1) and (col1, col2) usig the following query:

```
select col1, sum(col2) 
from table_one
group by grouping sets ((col1), (col1, col2))
```

Otherwise, you can group by col1 and rollup on col2 using the following query:

```
select col1, sum(col2) 
from table_one
group by col1, rollup(col2)
```

Both of these queries should produce the output you require.

Answer (score 1):

Use your current query as a sub query.  In the outer query, use a WHERE clause that eliminates the NULL value in Col1

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    -- Your Rollup Query goes here.
    SELECT * FROM MyTable
)
WHERE COL1 IS NOT NULL
```

A better solution was presented in the comments to eliminate NULL values in the source column(s)

Use the GROUPING function to determine if it is a a sub-total.

http://www.remote-dba.net/pl_sql/t_sql_grouping.htm

Comment: Rather than checking for col1 is not null, it's better to use the `grouping` or `grouping_id` functions to find if you are working with a superaggregate row or not. This query will fail if any of the source data in col1 is null.